# Language_check inheritance error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, pycharm, languagetool

I wanted to create my own class `Corr_tool` which inherits from class `language_check.LanguageTool`. But it throws me bunch of errors. I would like to ask, if there is some rule I am not aware of, because with other imported classes, inheritance works without any problem.

This is my code  :

```
from language_check import LanguageTool

class Corr_tool(LanguageTool):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(language='en-GB')

tool1 = Corr_tool()
```

Errors looks like this :

```
in <module> tool1 = Correct_tool()
in __init__ super().__init__(language='en-GB')
in __init__ self._language = LanguageTag(language)
in __new__ return str.__new__(cls, cls._normalize(tag))
in _normalize for language in get_languages()}
in get_languages languages = LanguageTool._get_languages()
in _get_languages cls._start_server_if_needed()
in _get_languages ls._start_server_if_needed()
in _start_server_if_needed cls._start_server_on_free_port()
in _start_server_on_free_port cls._start_local_server()
in _start_local_server startupinfo=startupinfo
in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session)
line 1155, in _execute_child startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Am I missing something ? 
Thank you for any explanation or help.

**EDIT**

When I use this code :

```
from language_check import LanguageTool

tool1 = LanguageTool('en-GB')
text = u'A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker’s Guide tot he Galaxy'
matches = tool1.check(text)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

everything works fine. But when I try to inherit from this class, If get errors. I there would be problem with Windows, wouldn't that problem occur also with this code?

**EDIT 2**

It drives me crazy. Why this code works just fine :

```
from language_check import LanguageTool

tmp_tool = LanguageTool('en-GB')

class Corr_tool(LanguageTool):
    def __init__(self, lang):
        super().__init__(language = lang)

tool = Corr_tool('en-GB')
```

But this one doesn't work (and throws errors i already had written here) :

```
from language_check import LanguageTool

class Corr_tool(LanguageTool):
    def __init__(self, lang):
        super().__init__(language = lang)

tool = Corr_tool('en-GB')
```

Comment: Do you have the same error when you do >>> import language_check
>>> tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-GB') ?

Comment: Yes, i do. I have already tried it this way..

Comment: Sooo it is not an inheritance issue.. Parameter 'en-GB' is wrong or there was a problem during installation

Comment: When i use LamguageTool alone, it works fine. It throws error only in this case of inheritance.

Comment: I don't get it. You just told me you had same error without inheritance. Please provide the code with LanguageTool alone then

Answer (score 0):

```
from language_check import LanguageTool

class Corr_tool(LanguageTool):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(language='en-GB')

tool = Corr_tool()
text = u"A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker's Guide tot he Galaxy"
matches = tool.check(text)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

No error

Prints :

```
Line 1, column 17, Rule ID: EN_A_VS_AN
Message: Use 'an' instead of 'a' if the following word starts with a vowel sound, e.g. 'an article', 'an hour'
Suggestion: an
A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker’s Guide tot he ...
                ^
Line 1, column 32, Rule ID: MORFOLOGIK_RULE_EN_GB
Message: Possible spelling mistake found
Suggestion: Hitch-hiker
A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker’s Guide tot he Galaxy
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
Line 1, column 51, Rule ID: TOT_HE[1]
Message: Did you mean 'to the'?
Suggestion: to the
... with a error in the Hitchhiker’s Guide tot he Galaxy
```

Looks like everything is fine with python v3.6.4, language_check v1.1 and java 1.8 on Windows 8

Comment: I used Windows 8

Comment: I literally copied your code and it throws error. But when i don't use inheritance and i call only `LanguageTool('en-GB')`, it works.

Comment: Did you have same error or encoding error ? I updated my post as there was a non utf8 character, could you try to run it again and give me the error raised ?

Comment: @SevO: it could be useful if you edited your exact OS and Python version into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the library is not compatible with Windows. The `OSError` code (`87`) relates to trying to create a new process by forking (which is not available on Windows).

Your options are:

- port your code to a compatible platform. eg. GNU/Linux, OSX or BSD.
- find another library
- convince your library author to make the module compatible with Windows. That seems unlikely, given that [this feature request](https://github.com/myint/language-check/issues/7) seems to be been made back in 2015, but is still not implemented.